# Does DOM elements like a button's onclick function need to explicitly send event as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I'm finding out if an event handler needs to have the 'event' parameter be passed to it explicitly versus I have access to it implicitly

I've tried it with myHandler(event, 'hi') and I can access and do even.preventDefault but looking for ways so that I won't need to pass event here

```
<button onclick="hijackAddToCart(12345)">Add To Cart</button>

<script>
   hijackAddToCart(event, productId){
     event.preventDefault();

   // do something with productId
   }
</script>
```

I'm expecting the above code to have access to event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. By passing the event in your parameter only than your function can access the event DOM elements.

Answer (score 3):

Set first argument `event` and then your parameter `productId`.

```js
function hijackAddToCart(event, productId) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log(productId)
   // do something with productId
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hijackAddToCart(event, 12345)">Add To Cart</button>
```